# Struts 2 result, both stream and some values?

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I have a JQuery - Struts 2 application. I send a request by $.load() to struts action and I get a HTML content and every thing is fine. 
the problem is when I need to get the HTML content **along with** an integer that shows the status, **by a single** XMLHTTPRequest.

Actually, in my case, the HTML content is the new logs of the server process and the integer value is the status of that process.

How to send back the integer along with the content?

this is action config:

```
<action name="getProcessUpdate" class="ProcessAction" >
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">newLogs</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

this is in the action class:

```
public class ProcessAction extends ActionSupport {

    private InputStream newLogStream;

    public InputStream getNewLogs() {
        return newLogStream;
    }

    public String execute() {

        newLogStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getNewLogHTML().getBytes());

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private String getNewLogHTML(){
        String newLong = "";

        newLong = "Some new Longs";

        return newLong;
    }
}
```

And this is my jquery call:

```
function getNewLogs(){
    $( "#log" ).load('getProcessUpdate');
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the status of that process" ?

Comment: sorry if it was confusing, it's actually a flag that shows in which state my server side thread is. actually you can think of it as just an integer value which I need in client side as well. ok?

Comment: @mostafa.S Do you need to return an integer as a status from the `.load()`?

Comment: @RomanC that is exactly what I asked him and, according to his answer, no, it's not that (otherwise a simple CallBack with `function(response, status, xhr)` would have worked...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal result (instead of Stream), and return a JSP snippet with all the Action's object you want in it, then return it with `$.load()`.

Remember to prevent the escaping of your values in the snippet with `escape="false"`.

Struts.xml

```
<action name="getProcessUpdate" class="ProcessAction" >
    <result>snippet.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Action

```
public class ProcessAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String newLog;
    private Integer threadState;

    /* Getters */

    public String execute() {
        threadState = 1337;     
        newLog = getNewLogHTML();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Main JSP

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function getNewLogs(){
        $( "#container" ).load('getProcessUpdate');
    });
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

snippet.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<h3>Log file</h3>
<div id="log">
    <s:property value="newLog" escape="false" />
</div>

<h3>Thread state</h3>
<div id="threadState">
    <s:property value="threadState" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that, I do the log and status fetching on a timer, not once, so I don't want to append all the mentioned JSP into my already built div every time, I just need to append the new logs in the prepared div and use the status values in my java script code only. I just figured I can return a JSON result and extracts whatever I want from the object, what do you think?

Comment: Then you should use `$.ajax()` and [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `$.load`, and the snippet.jsp could only have the `<s:property value="newLog" escape="false" />` and a `<script>alert('<s:property value="threadState" />');</script>` script code... otherwise, go with JSON ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally chose a combination of my old inputStream method and the answer @Andrea posted: which is I will return piece of HTML including both my logs and my status, then in my java script code I will separate them, by making help of JQuery.

anyway I will accept @Andrea answer I guess because it was inspiring.

Thanks.